# Handling NotSupported exception

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using Scrapy Spider to scrape some data from websites, but not all links are nice. I am getting `NotSupported` error for some of them and I would like to store these url in a file or define some other behavior. Is there a way catch `scrapy.exceptions.NotSupported` and define custom behavior? 
I tried naively the following code, but it does not work.

```
try:
    yield scrapy.Request(url, callback=self.parse)
except scrapy.exceptions.NotSupported:
    self.logger.info(url)
```

Comment: what kind of urls are they ? can i get any single example ?

Comment: @ThunderMind typically, pdf, doc, ppt and other. So, yes, these should not be used, but I do not want to filter them in advance. I want scrapy to handle not supported urls and sort of blacklist them or sent somewhere (do something else).

Comment: What you want to do with them ? no need?, may be needed at the end ? or what ?

Comment: I want to record them to see which addresses where not processed and how many of them is there

Comment: What's the exact error traceback you get?

Comment: "Does not work" is a completely useless description of a problem. Please describe _exactly how_ it "does not work".

Answer (score 0):

When raised upon creating a [`Request`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Request) object, [`NotSupported`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/exceptions.html#notsupported) implies that you are providing a bad URL.

If the URL is extracted from an HTML response, the most likely cause is that the URL is relative, and `Request` can only take absolute URLs.

You can use [`response.urljoin(url)`](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/request-response.html#scrapy.http.Response.urljoin) instead of just `url` to fix that issue.